# Adding a method to a function that returns an element

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with a micro library for use within projects and I'm having difficulty adding a method to a function.

In this case I have shorthanded `document.querySelector()` which is all good and works as needed. However I have no real idea how to add a method to that which inherits the element from the selector function.

This is similar to how jquery works but a lot of code examples online are a fair few years old. I'm wanting a modern solution and to understand how this works going forward. I really hope someone can educate me and help to get this to work.

Cheers!

```
let S = (selector, container = document) => {
    return container.querySelector(selector);
};

S.prototype = {
  classAdd: (_class) => this.classList.add(_class) 
};

S('div').classAdd('red');
```

https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/NMqBLp?editors=0010

Comment: Check their github page, can see how they do it: [jQuery() function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L33)

Comment: In arrow functions, the `this` keyword refers to the outer object (in this case, the window object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your code, shall we?

**First block**:

```
let S = (selector, container = document) => {
  return container.querySelector(selector);
};
```

This code declares a **simple function** and assigns function reference to variable `S`
The function itself returns HTML element as per [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) documentation, which can not be use in a chain notation:

```
S('div').something();  // won't work
let ele = S('div');    // works
```

**Second block:**

```
S.prototype = {
  classAdd: (_class) => this.classList.add(_class) 
};
```

Because `S` is a simple function (NOT a Function-Object) it has no **prototype** element as a regular Object does. However, the code still works as it creates a new property named `propotype` on the `S` function.

To prove what has been stated above, I have created following code example:

```js
let S = (selector, container = document) => {
  return container.querySelector(selector);
};

let ele = S('div');
console.log(ele);

S.prototype = {
  classAdd: (_ele, _class) => _ele.classList.add(_class)
};

S.prototype.classAdd(ele, 'red');
```

```css
.red {
  padding: 10rem;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div>Text inside div</div>
```

If you want to use chain notation such as `S('div').classAdd(..)` your first block function must return a valid object to act upon

```js
let S = (selector, container = document) => {
  return {
    ele : container.querySelector(selector),
    classAdd: function(_class) { // regular function notation as it needs this 
      this.ele.classList.add(_class) 
    }
  };
};

S('div').classAdd('red')
```

```css
.red {
  padding: 10rem;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div>Inside Div</div>
```

Comment: Good breakdown, I managed to progress and only have 2 issues left to solve before i can get this working and gain the understanding https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/jxPdqo?editors=0010

Comment: My issues are that logging `S('div')` return the object which i would expect however i ideally want the element itself.

Comment: To achieve `S(selector)[0]` how can i do that when i'm returning an object?

Comment: As you use `querySelector` there is only one matching element (or none at all). So to get it, use `S.ele`

Answer (score 3):

[Arrow functions don't have a prototype property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Use_of_prototype_property). To get it working use a normal function, that's not not modern. Arrow functions are not a replacement, but an addition. You could also use a class though - maybe that's what you mean with modern.

```js
class S {
  constructor(selector, container = document) {
    this.selected = container.querySelector(selector);
  }

  classAdd(clazz) {
    this.selected.classList.add(clazz);
  }
}

new S('#foo').classAdd('bar');
console.log('#foo has bar as class: ', document.getElementById('foo').classList.contains('bar'));
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  foo
</div>
```

Comment: I did try a normal function but that also did not work, https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/NMqBLp?editors=0010

Comment: using the class syntax is nice however i would prefer a functional approach

Comment: Well, like I wrote, use a normal function then... @matt3224

Comment: Thanks @baao but I can't get that to work, see this updated pen https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/vjOvoe?editors=0010

Comment: Okay now i have something that works using revealing module but is there anyway i can just get the element if i console.log `S('div')`? https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/jxPdqo?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

you can define `classAdd` in the `S` and return an object containing the methods :

```js
let S = (selector, container = document) => {
  let element = container.querySelector(selector);

  return {
    classAdd: (_class) => {      
      element.classList.add(_class)
    }
  }
};

S('div').classAdd('hello')
```

```html
<div>
  hello
</div>
```

Comment: This is cool, however i need to `S('div')` to work independently too

Comment: i'm having trouble understanding what you mean by `independent` , can you explain that with an example ?